# Internet filterer?

Tags: internet, firewall, filter

I'm looking for an app that will alert me and ask me whenever an app wants to access an internet connection then prompt me to decide wether to allow it or not. It would also be nice if the application shows what URL the blocked app was trying to access. I'm pretty sure I stumbled across an app like this on the Play Store before but I forgot what its name was and now, I can't seem to find it anymore.

I'm rooted so rooted/unrooted solutions are accepted.

I tried both DroidWall and LBE Privacy Guard. They both don't include the URL or website that an application accesses. :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure what you're asking for is a *firewall*, so by searching for that I've found what seems to be a very popular app that might work for you:

> [DroidWall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free&hl=en) - Front-end application for the powerful iptables Linux
>   firewall. Allows you to restrict which apps can access the network.

I tried finding some other alternatives for you, but every page I find seem to list this firewall as a recommendation, so it might be either really good or there might not be a lot of firewall apps out there (or both) :)

It does require root. Happy firewalling!

Comment: Does DroidWall let me see what URL the application is attempting to access?

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of [LBE Privacy Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite).  It needs root and can grant or deny other apps various permissions on a case-by-case basis.

Whether you trust a security solution from an otherwise unknown Chinese vendor is for you to decide.

Comment: Does LBE Privacy Guard let me see what URL the application is attempting to access?

Comment: I honestly do not remember.  (Anyway, showing an URL does not make much sense unless the app in question is making an HTTP request and not any other kind of IP traffic, no?)

Comment: I just tried LBE and I thought it worked with the prompting and all, the problem is, it doesn't prompt for internet access. It only prompts for other things like when an app is attempting to send SMS, trying to get GPS, etc. but not if an app is trying to access the internet.

Comment: I see.  I'm sorry for misleading you -- seems like I haven't remembered what it does all that well. :(